Location to place programming examples in DEB package in Linux
I'm creating a DEB package for my application but I don't have much experience in Linux.
I've checked the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy guide and I've figured out that:

binary files should go in /usr/bin/myprogram/
configuration files should go in /etc/myprogram/
general documentation files should go in /usr/share/doc/myprogram/

But the program also has an API so the package should provide a set of programming examples for the user, but to be honest, I don't know what should be the right location or path for these files.
Any help will be much appreciated.

The best way to figure out (and to get also many more details): look for similar packages, and check how maintainers did them. Users want uniformity. in general: examples are documentation.

That's my recommendation as well. Some packages ship something like examples/ in a directory in /usr/share/doc/<package>/. If the code snippets are reusable (like Python packages you can import, for example) install them in the correct library directory or similar.

Thank you. I'll do what you suggested. It seems that placing the examples at /usr/share/doc//examples/ is the most logical and intuitive place

The established convention is that examples are found in /usr/share/doc/$package/examples/.
On my system, almost 300 packages provide their examples that way:
$ printf '%s\n' /usr/share/doc/*/examples/ | wc -l
292

